# Type mismatch when trying to multiply cell values with each other

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to multiply two different values from two cells. The multiplication is different based on a value in a third cell range. Currently I'm using If statement but I've tried Select Case solution before with the same result, which is that the multiplication gives the type mismatch error. Thank you in advance for your help. The code is:

```
 Sub multichoice_convert()

 Dim KonverterSheet As Worksheet
 Set KonverterSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("KONVERTER")

 Dim masolniSheet As Worksheet
 Set masolniSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ide masolni")

 Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
 Set dataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data")

 Dim fejlecRange As Range
 Set fejlecRange = masolniSheet.Range("A1:Z1")

 Dim copiedfejlec As Range
 Set copiedfejlec = KonverterSheet.Range("A1:Z1")

 Dim copiedpenznem As Range
 Set copiedpenznem = copiedfejlec.Find("Pénznem", LookAt:=xlWhole)

 Dim copieduccsósor As Long
 copieduccsósor = KonverterSheet.Cells(KonverterSheet.Rows.Count, copiedpenznem.Column).End(xlUp).Row

 Dim copiedaroszlop As Range
 Set copiedaroszlop = copiedfejlec.Find("Ár", LookAt:=xlWhole)

 Dim copiedtartomany As Range
 Set copiedtartomany = KonverterSheet.Range(copiedpenznem.Offset(1, 0), 
 copiedpenznem.Offset(copieduccsósor - copiedpenznem.Row))

 Dim penznemcella As Range
 For Each penznemcella In copiedtartomany


If penznemcella = "EUR" Then
Set penznemertek = dataSheet.Range("B1")
End If
If penznemcella = "US$" Then
Set penznemertek = dataSheet.Range("B2")
End If
If penznemcella = "DKK" Then
Set penznemertek = dataSheet.Range("B3")
End If
If penznemcella = "GBP" Then
Set penznemertek = dataSheet.Range("B4")
End If
If penznemcella = "NKR" Then
Set penznemertek = dataSheet.Range("B5")
End If
If penznemcella = "SEK" Then
Set penznemertek = dataSheet.Range("B6")
End If
If penznemcella = "SGD" Then
Set penznemertek = dataSheet.Range("B7")
End If
If penznemcella = "SKR" Then
Set penznemertek = dataSheet.Range("B8")
End If
     
KonverterSheet.Cells(penznemcella.Row, "E") = KonverterSheet.Cells(penznemcella.Row, 
copiedaroszlop.Column) * penznemertek

Next penznemcella

End Sub
```

Comment: What are the values and their data types of all the variables in that line, when it halts because of the returned error?

Comment: I strongly recommend that you use proper indentation in your code. It will make life a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

The Type mismatch error 13 is just that - there is a mismatch in the types of the variables you are using in the statement which causes the error.
You probably have some text or non-numerical values (N/A, #NUM, blank etc) in either KonverterSheet.Cells(penznemcella.Row, copiedaroszlop.Column) or penznemertek (or the underlying cells).

To test for the values add some code using debug.print to display in the 'Immediate' window. E.g. the following will print the values to the immediate window before trying to do the multiplication and should make it clear what it's trying to do when you inspect your code after the error:

```
debug.print "Trying to multiply " & KonverterSheet.Cells(penznemcella.Row, copiedaroszlop.Column) & " with " & penznemertek
KonverterSheet.Cells(penznemcella.Row, "E") = KonverterSheet.Cells(penznemcella.Row, copiedaroszlop.Column) * penznemertek
```

Alternatively, you can set watches on variables you want to keep an eye on. (Learn to use the IDE and you will find lots of ways of debugging.)

Answer (score 0):

Please consider this code instead of your existing (at the end of your procedure). Note that the procedure is untested and might contain typos which please point out to me.

```
Dim penznemcella    As Range
Dim Ccy()           As String
Dim i               As Integer
Dim Rate            As Double
Dim penznem         As Double
For Each penznemcella In copiedtartomany
    Ccy = Split("EUR USD DKK GBP NKR SEK SGD SKR")
    For i = UBound(Ccy) To 0 Step -1
        If srtcomp(penznemcella.Value, Ccy(i), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then Exit For
    Next i
    If i < 0 Then
        MsgBox "Currency """ & penznemcella.Value & """ not understood"
    Else
        penznem = Val(dataSheet.Cells(i + 1, "B").Value)
        Rate = Val(KonverterSheet.Cells(penznemcella.Row, copiedaroszlop.Column))
        KonverterSheet.Cells(penznemcella.Row, "E") = penznem * Rate
    End If
Next penznemcella
```

The point of this code is in the use of the Val() function to force whatever is in the referenced cells into a variable of double data type. If this fails for some reason, e.g. if the cell contains a string, Val() will generate a value of zero. If the cell contains an error Val() will receive an error and issue an error. Such errors are easy to trap if that's what you need (you will probably be more interested in setting up your procedures so that no error can occur at that point).